# How to COUNT in MySQL with CASE stament

Tags: mysql, sql, count, case, mysql-workbench

I have the following query

```
SELECT CASE u.situacionUsuario 
    WHEN "A" THEN 'ALTA'
    WHEN "R" THEN 'ALTA'
    WHEN "S" THEN 'ALTA'
    WHEN "B" THEN 'BAJA'
    WHEN "T" THEN 'BAJA'
    ELSE NULL
    END AS Situacion
FROM Usuario u
WHERE 
YEAR(u.fechaAsistencia)=2018 AND MONTH(u.fechaAsistencia) BETWEEN 01 AND 12
GROUP BY u.situacionUsuario, u.usuario;
```

That return this result

```
-Situacion-
|ALTA     |
|ALTA     |
|ALTA     |
|ALTA     |
|ALTA     |
|ALTA     |
|BAJA     |
|BAJA     |
|ALTA     |
|ALTA     |
|ALTA     |
|BAJA     |
|ALTA     |
|ALTA     |
|ALTA     |
----------
```

And the result that i want is this one.

```
-Situacion-TOTAL-|
|ALTA     |12    |
|BAJA     |3     |
-----------------
```

I used COUNT but it dosn't return the result i want

```
SELECT CASE u.situacionUsuario 
        WHEN "A" THEN 'ALTA'
        WHEN "R" THEN 'ALTA'
        WHEN "S" THEN 'ALTA'
        WHEN "B" THEN 'BAJA'
        WHEN "T" THEN 'BAJA'
        ELSE NULL
        END AS Situacion,
    COUNT (CASE u.situacionUsuario 
        WHEN "A" THEN 'ALTA'
        WHEN "R" THEN 'ALTA'
        WHEN "S" THEN 'ALTA'
        WHEN "B" THEN 'BAJA'
        WHEN "T" THEN 'BAJA'
        ELSE NULL
        END) AS Total
    FROM Usuario u
    WHERE 
    YEAR(u.fechaAsistencia)=2018 AND MONTH(u.fechaAsistencia) BETWEEN 01 AND 12
    GROUP BY Situacion;
```

Any suggestion how can i COUNT with the cases and get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write this as:

```
SELECT (CASE u.situacionUsuario 
           WHEN 'A' THEN 'ALTA'
           WHEN 'R' THEN 'ALTA'
           WHEN 'S' THEN 'ALTA'
           WHEN 'B' THEN 'BAJA'
           WHEN 'T' THEN 'BAJA'
        END) AS Situacion,
       COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM Usuario u
WHERE u.fechaAsistencia >= '2018-01-01' AND
      u.fechaAsistencia < '2019-01-01' 
GROUP BY Situacion;
```

Notes:

- Strings should be delimited by single quotes.  Your code would fail to work -- for instance -- if `Usuario` had any columns named `A` or `R` and so on.
- Use direct date comparisons instead of date functions in the `WHERE` clause, when possible.  This improves optimization.
- MySQL supports column aliases in the `GROUP BY`.
- I'm not sure why you would want `0` if the row is `NULL`, so this just uses `COUNT(*)` for the total.
- `ELSE NULL` is redundant.  I don't think it adds anything to the query.

I would actually simplify this to:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN u.situacionUsuario IN ('A', 'R', 'S') THEN 'ALTA'
             WHEN u.situacionUsuario IN ('B', 'T')  THEN 'BAJA'
        END) AS Situacion,
       COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM Usuario u
WHERE u.fechaAsistencia >= '2018-01-01' AND
      u.fechaAsistencia < '2019-01-01' 
GROUP BY Situacion;
```

This reduces the likelihood of a tpo in the query causing unexpected results.

Comment: Thank you for answer, your solution gave me the approach I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Do the `CASE` part in a derived table. `GROUP BY` its result:

```
select Situacion, count(*) as TOTAL
from
(
    SELECT CASE u.situacionUsuario 
        WHEN "A" THEN 'ALTA'
        WHEN "R" THEN 'ALTA'
        WHEN "S" THEN 'ALTA'
        WHEN "B" THEN 'BAJA'
        WHEN "T" THEN 'BAJA'
        ELSE NULL
        END AS Situacion
    FROM Usuario u
    WHERE 
    YEAR(u.fechaAsistencia)=2018 AND MONTH(u.fechaAsistencia) BETWEEN 01 AND 12
) dt
GROUP BY Situacion
```

Comment: `count(*) as TOTAL`?

Answer (score 0):

try embedded selection,

```
select Situacion, count（Situacion） from （

SELECT CASE u.situacionUsuario 
    WHEN "A" THEN 'ALTA'
    WHEN "R" THEN 'ALTA'
    WHEN "S" THEN 'ALTA'
    WHEN "B" THEN 'BAJA'
    WHEN "T" THEN 'BAJA'
    ELSE NULL
    END AS Situacion
FROM Usuario u
WHERE 
YEAR(u.fechaAsistencia)=2018 AND MONTH(u.fechaAsistencia) BETWEEN 01 AND 12

） group by Situacion;
```